# Проект c++ не видит библиотеку, подключенную через CMake

Tags: c++, clion, jni, cmakelists

Всем привет. Никак не получается подключить `jni` к моему проекту в `CLion`. При попытке подключить заголовочный файл `jni` получаю ошибку `'jni.h' file not found`. Сам `CMakeLists` выглядит так:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(FirstLib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(FirstLib library.cpp library.h Entity.h Entity.cpp)
include_directories(C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/include)
include_directories(C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/include/linux)
link_directories(C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/include)
link_directories(C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/include/linux)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В кавычки пути возьмите,  а так получается что вы две директории подключаете

Comment: Перезагрузите проект cmake.

Comment: @Rikitikitavi спасибо, помогло